# How to make VSCode resolve "@" in imports

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, visual-studio-code

I'm working in a Vue.js project that uses Webpack. Many imports use `@` as an alias to `src` directory. How can VSCode be configured to resolve the alias and make intellisense work with those imports?

I have found in many places on the web how to setup aliases in VSCode, using `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json`. I have tried configuring in both files and nothing seems to work.

My jsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

I expected VSCode to resolve the alias in the path, making intellisense and peeking definition work.

Answer (score 12):

In my current project, I have a `jsconfig.json` at the root containing this :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "docs"]
}
```

and it works for me.

I don't know exactly what `moduleResolution` is doing in your conf, and my `baseUrl` is the root folder in my case.

The related doc for vs code : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases

Try it and tell me if it's working better ?

Comment: yes, this is the way I have it working in a create-react-app with @material-ui...basically all of those items are in the paths object and everything works as normal.

Comment: FWIW, moduleResolution is TS thing. I'm not sure it's legit in jsconfig.json

Comment: I just threw moduleResolution there to try solving, but nothing has changed

Comment: I tried changing my target to es2017 and removed src from baseUrl, still doesn't work. I even tested with different projects and in another PC without success

Comment: @MathieuD. I can't because it's a private repository